postgresql how to change column in python
I accidentally wrote a bunch of tables with abbreviated column names and want to edit them.
obviously
ALTER TABLE [$table_name]
RENAME COLUMN "h" TO "high";

ALTER TABLE [$table_name]
RENAME COLUMN "v" TO "volume";

ALTER TABLE [$table_name]
RENAME COLUMN "o" TO "open";

etc, works in Navicat but I'd have to search separately and type in each table name one by one plus if one of the columns is not found for any reason, it just stops the rest of the query. Anyway, I tried
        with engine.connect() as conn:
        inspector = inspect(engine)
        for table_name in inspector.get_table_names():
            columns = [col["name"] for col in inspector.get_columns(table_name)]
            if x in columns:
                # Generate and execute the ALTER TABLE command
                query = text(f'ALTER TABLE "{table_name}" RENAME COLUMN "{x}" TO "{y}";')
                conn.execute(query)
                columns = [col["name"] for col in inspector.get_columns(f"{table_name}")]
                print("Updated columns:", columns)
                print(f'Renamed column "{x}" to "{y}" in table "{table_name}".')

in python and while the print statements will tell me everything changed fine, the actual columns will remain unchanged.
ps - and if anyone knows how I would be able to automate this in navicat? Automate seems to just run a query multiple times without my being able to change the parameters, how can I loop through, get a list, and change the tables listed?

I'm going to say you need a conn.commit() after the change queries are done to have the changes committed.

I would rather write an anonymous PL/pgSQL DO block in Navicat which loops over names' array.
